# Substitute special characters for a text in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to come up a script for me substitute few special characters for texts in Python, here is a list of characters I want to replace:

:   <   >   ?   *   /   "  |   \

My code works well, if I don't add \ into the list I want to replace:

```
import re

subj='Test/ US: Paper* Packaging'

chars_to_remove = [':','<','>','?','*','/','"','|']
rx = '[' + re.escape(''.join(chars_to_remove)) + ']'
re.sub(rx, '', subj)
```

However, when I add \ into my chars_to_remove list, i will give me the error:SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

```
import re

chars_to_remove = [':','<','>','?','*','/','"','|','\']
rx = '[' + re.escape(''.join(chars_to_remove)) + ']'
re.sub(rx, '', subj)
```

I know \ means add a newline in Python, but here how can I let my code knows 
mean the character not newline.

Thanks